# Correct way of implementing Sessions and Cookies in PHP?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm simple not able to handle the correct way of implementing Cookies and Sessions. I have everytime another error when I think I implemented the code properly.

When the user register or login I run this code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $user_id;
$_SESSION['SESS_USER_NAME'] = $user_username;
$_SESSION['SESS_USER_EMAIL'] = $user_email;
$_SESSION['SESS_LOGGED'] = TRUE;
session_write_close();

setcookie("COOK_USER_ID",$user_id,time()+(3600*24*365));
setcookie("COOK_USER_NAME",$user_username,time()+(3600*24*365));
setcookie("COOK_USER_EMAIL",$user_email,time()+(3600*24*365));
setcookie("COOK_LOGGED",TRUE,time()+(3600*24*365));
```

On every page I want to protect I run this code:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGED']) && isset($_COOKIE['COOK_LOGGED']))
{ 
} 
elseif (isset($_COOKIE['COOK_LOGGED'])) {
    $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $_COOKIE['COOK_USER_ID'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_USER_NAME'] = $_COOKIE['COOK_USER_NAME'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_USER_EMAIL'] = $_COOKIE['COOK_USER_EMAIL'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_LOGGED'] = TRUE;
    session_write_close();
}
else { 
     include_once("register.php");
     exit();
}
```

And when the user logs off I run this code:

```
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    //Destroy Session
    session_start();
    $_SESSION = array(); 
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php");

    //Unset the Cookies
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
        $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
        foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
            $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
            $name = trim($parts[0]);
            setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
            setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
        }
    }
    exit();
}
```

But when I close the browser and start it again, there is always a weird behavior where the cookies are not set properly etc.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. On all pages I run at first `ob_start();` so the problem can't be a header related one.

Comment: You don't need to store the session data in extra cookies . The session_start() stores a cookie on the client side and php uses that cookie to identify the user's session and it's data . You're just overcomplicating things by storing same data twice on 2 sides (client && server) . When user loggs in just set a session array element "loged_in" and when it logs out , destroy that session .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I thought sessions are deleted when the browser/app is closed, while a cookie survives this procedure... isn't it?

Comment: A session is identified by a cookie. The session lives on the server. For the server to determine what session to use it uses the cookie that lives on the client. So just ignore cookies and let PHP deal with them to identify the session.

Comment: you can use session_name() to get the session name (cookie name of the session) , and after that use set_cookie to override the session cookie time limit

Comment: @EdHeal and @Geo C. thanks for the answer, but how can i manage that the session survives a browser restart? `session_set_cookie_params(3600*24*365,"/");` doesn't work when i put that line in front of every `session_start();`

Comment: @JohnBrunner - You do realize that that IP addresses are shared so if the user restarts the browser it is a good idea to restart the session.

Comment: @EdHeal sorry, no i don't get it. i deleted all the cookie stuff and now the session behave like i said before... it will be deleted after a browser restart. when i look on google for "remember me" functions everyone is talking about cookies, because they survive the browser restart.

Comment: @JohnBrunner Cookies and Sessions are two different concepts. Have a cookie to store some data but not to resurrect a session Use a cookie to fill in a form.

Comment: @EdHeal thanks. so you mean i should make a authentication system with sessions and a database, where i store the users ip and other data i get from his browser? or which way do you recommend (and is simple enough) for just giving the user the benefit that he don't has to log in every time he opens the website?

Comment: @JohnBrunner - Use cookies to get the form/web page delivered with some entries filled in (e.g. username). Create sessions when the user logs in and store details on the server side as to what is ordered etc. This is time depended and should dissolve into the ether other a period of time.